# Nokogiri can get og:image in some sites

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri to parse HTML and get the `og:image` value:

```
def get_og_image url
  html = open(url, "r:binary").read                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html.toutf8, nil, 'utf-8')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

  if doc.css("meta[property='og:image']").present?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    img_path = doc.css("meta[property='og:image']").first.attributes["content"].value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  end 

  img_path
end
```

now

```
> get_og_image "http://techcrunch.com/2014/08/05/the-hug-a-water-bottle-sensor-and-app-helps-you-stay-hydrated/"
=> "http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/the-hug_office.jpg?w=680"

> get_og_image "http://www.yahoo.co.jp/"
=> nil
```

However yahoo.co.jp has og:image value:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://k.yimg.jp/images/top/ogp/fb_y_1500px.png">
```

How can I get the right og:image in Nokogiri?

Comment: We need a minimal sample of your input HTML you're having trouble with, that is sufficient to duplicate the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that website has an og:image? I just checked it with curl and it og:image is no where to be found.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I solved my problem. It's a problem of UA.

Answer (score 0):

The response HTML of "http://www.yahoo.co.jp/", which I had trouble with, is changed by User Agent.

I set a dummy user-agent when I access the URL with Nokogiri and then I can get the og:image.

Comment: You need to differentiate between what OpenURI does vs. Nokogiri. OpenURI is opening the URL and retrieving the content. It is what needs to pass the User-Agent string, and then returns the content, either as a StringIO, or a string, depending on how you use `open`. Nokogiri then parses that by reading the file and/or parsing the string. At no time does Nokogiri care about the URL itself or a User-Agent string.